# What's the difference between 上で and 次第？

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what was the difference between 上で and 次第. As for their significance I think that they differ a little. On one end, 上で bears the meaning of "upon doing something", whilst 次第 implies that "as soon something it's done, also something else can be done". There are are differences that I have overseen? May I also add that I'm not sure whether to use 上で and てから？

Comment: You pretty much answered your question by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Xした上で{うえで} Yをする implies you are required to do X before doing Y. The following sentences from [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17265/meaning/m0u/) :

> 予約の時間を確認のうえご来店ください

```
Please come to our shop after making sure your reservation time.
```

> もう一度診断をしたうえで、手術の日時を決めることにしよう

`Let's decide the date of the operation based on another diagnosis.`

X次第でYをする describes the situation of X will occur Y. My example sentence is following :

> 2人の選手の試合結果次第で、オリンピックに行けるかどうか決まる。

```
Depends on the result of two players' match, it decides whether you can go Olympic Games or not.
```

~てから can be interchangeble with 上で in informal.

Comment: OPが言ってる「次第」は、「結果次第で」(depending on~) とかの「次第」じゃなくて、「連絡が入り次第、～」「到着次第、～」(as soon as~~) とかの「次第」みたいですけど？　`as soon something it's done, also something else can be done` と書いておられますし。

Comment: 曲解しているようです。詳細なご解説ありがとうございます。とりあえず、OPがもっとスペシフィックに回答して欲しいと言うまでご放念いただけますでしょうか。